# How to connect other objects to a displaced surface generated by a noise texture shader with animation

Tags: shaders, displacement, linked-data

I created a very simple wave plane through shader editor. It is based on a noise texture feeding a vector displacement node which connected to displacement channel within material output node. This surface is animated by rotation manipulation within mapping node.

It resemble ocean modifier but I seek an artificial look which I can achieve by this shader.

I am wondering how to connect other objects (spheres or cubes) to this displaced surface by a noise texture manipulation?

-K

Comment: shrinkwrap modifier?

Comment: I don't think that you can with the Displacement node, you need to use the Displace modifier for example

Comment: Thanks Chris & moonboots for the hints. So far it looks similar which is good but the animation is kinda painful compared to mapping node manipulation.

Comment: No it's pretty easy, in the modifier, choose Coordinates > Object with an empty as object, move the empty, it animates the texture

Comment: Actually, this is what I did to connect the object with displaced surface as you described - moonboots but it feels painful for me when I compare it with mapping node manipulation right away. Unfortunately, there is no way to extract that vector data easily. Maybe I have to go with python script, I guess. Anyway, it's working fine now and the result it quite similar to first shader. Thanks for your help again.